# How to use proxy with WebDriverIO and PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver, phantomjs, webdriver-io

I'm using [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io) with PhantomJS to test a Website. However, I would like to use an HTTP proxy-server with authentication.

- I've tried to use [proxy settings from Selenium documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#proxy-json-object):

```
var client = webdriver.remote({
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    proxy: {
      proxyType: 'manual',
      httpProxy: proxyServer.ipAddress + ':' + proxyServer.httpPort,
      socksUsername: proxyServer.username,
      socksPassword: proxyServer.password
    }
  }
});
```

But, I can't open any URL with these settings. Nothing happens.

However, when I use `firefox` or `chrome` as `browserName` it's starting to load the page, but asking for username and password for some reason.

- I've also tried to pass [PhantomJS CLI arguments](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html):

```
var client = webdriver.remote({
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.cli.args': [
      '--proxy-type=http',
      '--proxy=' + proxyServer.ipAddress + ':' + proxyServer.httpPort,
      '--proxy-auth=' + proxyServer.username + ':' + proxyServer.password
    ].join(' ')
  }
});
```

But, traffic is not tunneled through proxy, it just uses my regular IP address.

SO, how do I configure WebdriverIO to use proxy?

Comment: so nothing? only thing i can find is this https://vimmaniac.com/blog/bangal/selenium-chrome-driver-proxy-with-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching for the answer This worked for me really well with an HTTP proxy.

```
{ browserName: 'phantomjs',
  "proxy": {
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "httpProxy":"HOST:PORT"
  }
}
```

[Source Gist](https://gist.github.com/dahngeek/752ca52778913705f7204c57f359afb5) has more options you might want.

Comment: i case you haven't read the OP he needs `HTTP proxy-server with authentication`